# Alternate way to Prove or disprove $6\mid n(n+1)(n+2)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, divisibility

This is my proof, I'm wondering if I'm correct, and how to do without induction.

**My Work**

*Basis Step*

$$\frac{(1)(2)(3)}{6} = 1$$

*Inductive Hypothesis*

Assume that $\dfrac{k(k+1)(k+2)}{6} = d$ where $d \in \mathbb Z$

*Induction Step*

We must show $\frac{(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)}{6}$ is an integer

$$\frac{(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)}{6} = \frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{6} \cdot (k+3)$$

We know that:

$\dfrac{(k+1)(k+2)}{6} = \dfrac{1}{k}\cdot\dfrac{k(k+1)(k+2)}{6}$ by our inductive hypothesis we know this to be an integer

Therefore, by the closure property of integers under multiplication and addition, $\dfrac{(k+1)(k+2)}{6} \cdot (k+3)$ must be integer.

Comment: Here's a suggestion on how to do it without induction. At least one of the integers $n, n+1, n+2$ must be divisible by $3$, since they're consecutive. Similarly, at least one must be divisible by $2$. Hence, $2|n(n+1)(n+2)$ and $3|n(n+1)(n+2)$ and so $6|n(n+1)(n+2)$.

Comment: Just a side note here. The product of three consecutive integers always contains an even number and a number that is divisible by 3. So the product must be divisible by 6

Comment: Your proof is not correct. $\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{6}$ does *not* have to be an integer. E.g. take $k=6$

Comment: For any $n$ one of the three numbers $n, n+1, n+2$ is divisible by 3 and at least one of them is divisible by 2. So the product is divisible by 6.

Comment: @drhab True. How would I do the correct induction proof?

Comment: $(k+1)(k+2)(k+3) = k(k+1)(k+2) + 3(k+1)(k+2)$. First term is divisible by 6 by inductive hypothesis. And the second term as well as one of $k+1,k+2$ is divisible by 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Without induction:*

At least one of $n, n+1, n+2$ is even and exactly one is divisible by three. Hence $2 \ | \ n(n+1)(n+2)$ and $3 \ | \ n(n+1)(n+2)$. As $2$ and $3$ are co-prime, this means $6 \ | \ n(n+1)(n+2)$.

Comment: I realize why one must be exactly even, but why must one be divisible by 3?

Comment: Because $n \equiv 0, 1$ or $2 \mod 3$. And hence $n + 1 \equiv 1, 2$ or $0$ respectively; and $n + 2 \equiv 2, 0$ or $1$ respectively.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using induction:

Let $6|n(n+1)(n+2)$.

It is clear that one of the factors $n+1$, $n+2$ is even, so that $2|(n+1)(n+2)$.

If also $3|(n+1)(n+2)$ then $6|(n+1)(n+2)$ and consequently $6|(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)$ and we are ready.

If $3\nmid\left(n+1\right)\left(n+2\right)$ then we can conclude that
$3\mid n$ . Then also $3\mid n+3$ resulting again in $6\mid\left(n+1\right)\left(n+2\right)\left(n+3\right)$.